# How do I use createUserWithEmailAndPassword() with StyledFirebaseAuth?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm trying to just sign in users which have their details already in database. I do not want to create new users, but with firebase.auth(that is the default) it creates new users if not already present.

```
return(
            <Container>
                <StyledFirebaseAuth uiConfig={uiConfig} firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()}/>
                
            
            </Container>
        )
```

```
const uiConfig={
    signInFlow:'popup',
    signInSuccessUrl :'/',
    signInOptions:[
        firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
    ]
    
}
```

I did try it with creating a manual form, but I want to try it with just StyledFirebaseAuth. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use EmailAuthProvider.EMAIL_LINK_SIGN_IN_METHOD instead of EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID